# Can you please tell me is this good formulation of the sentence?

Tags: grammar

Also, we can learn from the life experience that, despite the fact how the good person had been after he did 1 bad thing, then he is already the target of many criticizers.

Comment: please help me, I need it very much

Comment: Welcome. Glad to help but need a better question. Please! edit this by adding other sentences to tell us what you are trying to say. Any answer now would require us to make assumptions and list possibilities. I await your changes.

Comment: is the sentence which i wrote in the correct form. is it good or do i have some kind of grammar mistakes.

Comment: Proof-reading is off-topic here. Sorry.

Comment: Proofreading questions are off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified.

Comment: I can almost understand what I think you're trying to say.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would write it as "We can also learn from the life experience that, despite the fact that the person was good after their affliction, their hurtful action has already made them the target of many critics." I would suggest adding a little more detail, but this seems like the best way to write the sentence you stated. I hope this was helpful!

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a discussion site...it is Q&A only..hopefully supported by citations, sources, etc.

Comment: Two issues you should be aware of ... no disrespect. Using *I* in an answer hints at personal opinion, instead of authority. And with proofreading off-topic, correcting a bad sentence invites more off-topic questions.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this site.  First question I read was yours. I wondered if I could offer anything of value, so I tried to stay pertinent to the main context of your sentence, shortening it, while keeping your pertinent points.
I hope I helped? If not, I hope your day is a good one MathBoy!

"Life experience reveals no matter how good a person has been after committing an egregious act, there are those who will use his past against him."

Comment: thank you <3 have a nice day as well <3

Comment: You are welcome. Safety to you and yours :-)

Comment: Two issues you should be aware of ... no disrespect. Using *I* in an answer hints at personal opinion, instead of authority. And with proofreading off-topic, correcting a bad sentence invites more off-topic questions